# Can we initialize any class object by using static method inside it

Tags: java, class, java-time

I have seen that for initializing an object class we use constructor of the class or constructor of subclass of it.

like for a class Abc we use,
`Abc object = new Abc()`;

```
LocalTime t = LocalTime.now();
System.out.println(t);
```

but here we are initializing object t of class LocalTime using LocalTime.now which is static function of class and object is returning that return value of that static method only. And new hasn't been used as well. Can we initialize any class object by using static method inside it? Please Explain.

Comment: Yes. It's called the "factory pattern", because of your "Please Explain" I suspect his is homework.

Comment: @matt: It's not clear what "Yes" is in reference to, but if it's intended to answer "Can we initialize any class object by using static method inside it?" then the answer is "no", not "yes".

Comment: @JonSkeet why not? If you can edit a class to create a static method, then you can have that method return an instance of the class.

Comment: @matt: But you **can't** edit every class. If the answer is "yes" then how do you propose to create an instance of java.lang.Math by using one of its static methods, for example? My reading of the question is that the OP was under the impression that the use of a static method *implicitly* created an instance, and that's just not the case.

Comment: If I can write a static method on Math then I can just `Math getMath(){ return new Math();}` even though it's useless. Of course Math doesn't have a static method that returns a Math.

Comment: "If I can write a static method on Math" - but you can't. That's my point. You can only use static methods to create an instance of the class if either you can add that static method yourself *or* if it's already provided. That doesn't cover "any class" (i.e. it doesn't apply to all classes), and it's not something that's just magic due to static methods. It's something you can choose to do.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's because `LocalTime.now()` is *designed* to create an instance of `LocalTime`. It will be calling the constructor internally.

Compare that with (say) `Math.cos()` which returns a `double`. That doesn't create an instance of `java.lang.Math`.

Static methods which create (or at least return) instances of the type they're declared in are sometimes called *factory methods*. It's a pretty common pattern, but there's nothing about static methods that *automatically* creates an instance of the declaring type.

Comment: If you have a class that you can edit you can always create a static method that returns a new instance.

Comment: @matt: That's not in any way the same thing as "Can we initialize any class object by using static method inside it" though. If the question was "does every method perform addition" then the answer is "no" even though "if you have a class that you can edit you can always change every method to perform addition".

Comment: @JonSkeet I understood this but Can we use instance of class to print the value of method inside it. Like in question System.out.println(t); , here t is instance of class LocalTime but it's printing the return type of method LocalTime.now() . And generally in println we only use method which returns the value or some datatype which can be printed. How is it printing Instance of a class.

Comment: @Dr.Tre: That's an unrelated question, as far as I can tell. Please ask a new question instead. (Fundamentally, it's a matter of overriding `toString()`, but that's entirely separate to this question.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possibile to use static methods to create new objects. Generally to create a new instance using a static method you can do something similar to that:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static MyClass createInstance() {
        return new MyClass();
    }

    ...
}
```

This approach is useful for some design pattern that creates objects under certain conditions. For example the singleton pattern that must ensure that there is only one instance for a particular class has an implementation that can be something similar to:

```
public class MySingleton {
   private static MySingleton instance;

   // A private constructor can not be called from outside that class
   private MySingleton() {
   }

   public static MySingleton getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = new MySingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

There are also other implementations for the singleton that can be more efficient or useful in different contexts (for example double check with synchronized block) but this is a simple and useful example to show how to use a static method to create instances of a class.

Other design patterns using a similar approach using a static method to create instances are:

- abstract factory
- factory method
- building
- double checked locking (a particular version of the singleton working in multithread environments)